# Locate source project directory in Swift from compiled code

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to find the directory of my uncompiled source code (because I want to count the lines of it) in my own swift project.

```
let projectRepo = "/Users/tombrown/Workspace/SwiftGolf" // <-- I want this programmatically
let path = "\(projectRepo)/SwiftGolf/Golf.swift"

var fileContents = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

I've found the compiled location with `NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath`, but it doesn't contain the uncompiled code. Any thoughts? Maybe there's a way that I could write a temporary file during the build process?

Answer (score 2):

The challenge is getting swift to infer location at runtime vs compile time. The arguments in xcode suggestion works well and can be accepted as solution. I couldn't use this approach because I'm using SPM without xcode. Another approach could be to  use this library https://github.com/JohnSundell/Files

in you Package.swift

```
dependencies: [
          .Package(url: "https://github.com/JohnSundell/Files.git", Version(1,8,0))
    ]
```

then in your code

```
import Files
let projectRepo = "\(Folder.home.path)/gitWorkspace/SwiftGolf"
do {
 let model = try Data(contentsOf:URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(projectDir)/\(modelFile)"))

}catch {

   print("error: \(error)")

}
```

another option is CommandLineKit / xcode arguments

```
import CommandLineKit .  
let cmdLine = CommandLineKit.CommandLine() .    
let file = StringOption(shortFlag: "f",   
                    longFlag: "file",    
                    required: true,   
                    helpMessage: "The file you're trying to parse") .   
cmdLine.addOptions(file)


do {
    try cmdLine.parse()
    print(file.value!)   
} catch {
    print("error: \(error)")
    exit(-1)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As adding source files to `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources` doesn't work and to have more flexibility, I recommend to use a little tiny bit of Objective-C.

In the project's `Build Settings` add the following line:

[image: steps to add a macro]

and then if your project already has a bridging header the const will become available automatically from Swift

```
do {
    let path = "\(PROJECT_DIR)/Test/ViewController.swift"
    let source = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
    print(source)
} catch {
    print("Error handling goes here")
}
```

If the project doesn't have a bridging header then it's possible to make Xcode to add one by adding a new Objective-C class to the project and then Xcode will ask about the bridging header.

EDIT:

Also of course bridging header can be added manually, by adding a new header file to the project, and then setting its path to the "Objective-C Bridging Header" in project's Build Settings.

Usually the PROJECT_DIR macro will not be available to Swift code automatically, in the bridging header add:

```
@import Foundation;

static const NSString *kProjectDir = PROJECT_DIR;
```

END EDIT

---

If you are fine with readonly access to the files, you can make Xcode to copy the source files into the app's resource folder by adding a custom script or a `Copy Files` Build Phase like on the image:

[image: steps to add copy files phase]

Then the path to the file will be:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ViewController", ofType: "swift")
```

Comment: I can't access the preprocessor macro, even with the bridging-header
@wisenomad

Comment: It's true, sometimes the const isn't automatically available in Swift code. Then it can be mapped explicitly inside the bridging header like: `static const NSString *kProjectDir = PROJECT_DIR;`