# How can I open a txt file in local directory in swift2?

Tags: ios, file-io, swift2

I've put a "restaurants.txt" file in the same directory with MenuViewController.swift.
Then I put this code in viewDidLoad() of MenuViewController to read the file.

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("restaurants", ofType: "txt") {
        if let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            print(content)
        } else {
            print("error1")
        }
    } else {
        print("error")
    }
```

Then I get "error1" in my console.
How can I read the file in the same directory of the swift file?
Or do I have to put my "restaurants.txt" file somewhere else?

Comment: Have added the file to the project?

Answer (score 0):

Add the file to the target:

1. Select the file
2. In the Project Navigator <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> select the file icon
3. Under "Target Membership" click the checkbox for the file.

[image]

Comment: I've checked that but still get same problem @zaph

Comment: Look in the ipa to make sure the file is there and to see if it is in a directory. In Xcode select projects, select your project, click on the arrow icon at the end of the path, this will take you to the Derived Data folder. Double click your project folder and drill down to yourAppName.app file. Right click it and "Show Package Contents. Look for the file of interest and note any directory it is in, if it is in a sub-directory add that to the path.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you wish to read content of a text file, even without inserting it to your project, you may also use NSFileMananger. The following code works, the only drawback - you need to state full path.

```
let fullPath = "/your/full/path/restaurants.txt"
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fullPath){
        do
        {
            let content = try String(contentsOfFile: fullPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("\(content)")
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("error reading file: \(error)")
        }
}
```

2) If you do mind the hardcode, and want it more generic - you will have to change Settings in the Build in Xcode. See here: 
[Locate source project directory in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946085/locate-source-project-directory-in-swift-from-compiled-code)